# Multiple counts in single query with multiple joining of tables - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join three tables shown below into a single table.

Table: **Subjects**

```
Subject_id   Subject_Name
--------------------------
 1             English
 2             Arabic
 3             Hindi
```

Table : **Students**

```
Student_id     Student_Name    Subject_id
------------------------------------------
XXX               Veena            1
YYY                Ram             1
AAA                Raiza           2
DDD                David           3 
BBB                Geeth           3
```

Table : **StudentVsSubject**

```
Subject_id   Student_id      Status (1  =passed, 0 = failed)
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1             XXX             1
  2             AAA             0
  3             BBB             1
  3             DDD             0
```

And the **output** should be :

```
Subject TotalStudents  Passed   Failed  NotAttended
---------------------------------------------------
English    2            1          0          1
Arabic     1            0          1          0
Hindi      2            1          1          0
```

I'm stuck with by getting TotalStudents only.

```
SELECT Subjects.Subject_name
    ,count(Students.Students) AS TotalStudents
FROM Subjects
LEFT JOIN Students ON Subjects.Subject_id = Students.Subject_id
GROUP BY Subjects.Subject_name
```

Comment: Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. Note that I had to fix an inconsistency in your data, the second entry in `StudentVsSubject` should be `(2, 'AAA', 0)`, not `(2, 'YYY', 0)` as Student `AAA` took `Arabic`, not Student `YYY`. To get the `Passed` and `Failed` counts we simply `SUM` either `Status` or `1-Status`; to get the `NotAttended` count we `SUM` the `NULL` values from the `LEFT JOIN` to `StudentVsSubject`.

```
SELECT sb.Subject_Name, 
       COUNT(st.Student_id) AS TotalStudents,
       SUM(COALESCE(ss.Status, 0)) AS Passed,
       SUM(COALESCE(1 - ss.Status, 0)) AS Failed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ss.Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotAttended
FROM Subjects sb
JOIN Students st ON st.Subject_id = sb.Subject_id
LEFT JOIN StudentVsSubject ss ON ss.Subject_id = sb.Subject_id AND ss.Student_id = st.Student_id
GROUP BY sb.Subject_id, sb.Subject_Name
ORDER BY sb.Subject_id
```

Output:

```
Subject_Name    TotalStudents   Passed  Failed  NotAttended
English         2               1       0       1
Arabic          1               0       1       0
Hindi           2               1       1       0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5509a/5)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregated subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT  sub.Subject_name,
        a.TotalStudents,
        a.Passed,
        a.Failed
  FROM  Subjects sub
    LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT  Subject_id,
                        COUNT(Student_id) AS TotalStudents,
                        SUM(Status) AS Passed,
                        SUM(IIF(Status = 0, 1, 0)) AS Failed
                  FROM  StudentVsSubject
                  GROUP BY Subject_id
                ) a ON a.Subject_id = sub.Subject_id
```

Output (based on your above dataset):

```
Subject_name  TotalStudents  Passed  Failed
English       1              1       0
Arabic        1              0       1
Hindi         2              1       1
```